# How can I use Javascript generators in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, generator

I'm working on a survey module. I work with Vue.js and I wonder how I can use a javascript generator in Vue.

**Scenario**

The scenario is the following, the questions and answers for the survey are stored in a mysql database. I call this database with Axios so that the questions and answers are stored in the variable response.data.

**Expected Behavior**

My goal is to use a generator function to display the individual question and its answer choices and then click the button to display the next question and its answers.

For orientation, the final result should be functionally similar to the following feedback poll from hotjar: https://www.hotjar.com/feedback-polls/

**Code**

```js
Vue.component("frage", {
 props: ["frage"],
 template: "<h3> {{ frage }} </h3>",
});

let app = new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
   auswahl: [],
   picked: [],
   fragen: [],
   antworten: [],
   frage: [],
   count: 0,
   pool: [],
   gen: [],
 },

 mounted: function () {
   this.getAllFragen();
   this.gene();
 },

 methods: {
   Addcount: function () {
     console.log(this.fragen[this.count].quest);
     this.count += 1;
     let auswahl = this.fragen[this.count];
     this.frage = auswahl.quest;
     app.antworten = auswahl.answer;
   },

   werter: function () {
     this.pool.push(this.picked);
   },

   handler: function () {
     if (this.count <= this.fragen.length) {
       this.Addcount();
       this.werter();
       console.log(this.fragen.length);
     } else {
       console.log("No Handler");
     }
   },
   getAllFragen: function () {
     axios
       .post("../controller/readAdmin2Data.php")
       .then(function (response) {
         console.log(response.data);
         app.frage = response.data[app.count].quest;
         app.fragen = response.data;

         app.antworten = response.data[app.count].answer;
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
       });
   }
 }

 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the basic question is how do I use a generator in Vue.js. How do I integrate it, as a method or as a computed?

Comment: Because a generator function returns a different result on each call it cannot be used as computed (and also may have arguments as well which is not supported by computed properties).

Comment: This may not forward the conversation too far but Vue3 might have better 'support' for generator functions with the composition API.